# How can I add buttons that change the data variable visualization in my Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, choropleth

I'm trying to build a map on water system boundaries where users can click on buttons (water source type, cost of water, etc) that reference data in the GeoJSON layer to see that data on a choropleth map. Through a tutorial I've made a simple choropleth with one data variable but I'm struggling to figure out what the next step is to create buttons that could allow the user to switch between a few different variables. How do I add a button/click event that changes the variable read and map style?

```
  // based on the provided field, enter each value into the array
    geojson_data.features.forEach(function(item,index){
        values.push(item.properties[field])
    })

    // set up the "brew" options
    brew.setSeries(values);
    brew.setNumClasses(5);
    brew.setColorCode('YlOrRd');
    brew.classify('quantiles');

    // create the layer and add to map
    geojson_layer = L.geoJson(geojson_data,{
            style: getStyle,//call a function to style each feature
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature // actions on each feature 
            
            
    }).addTo(map);
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds(geojson_layer.getBounds())
        // create the legend
        createLegend();
        // create the infopanel
        createInfoPanel();
}
// style each feature
function getStyle(feature){
    return {
        stroke: true,
        color: 'white',
        weight: 1,
        fill: true,
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties['POPULATION']),
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    }
}
// return the color for each feature
function getColor(d) {

    return d > 5000000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 1000000 ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 500000 ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100000  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50000  ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 30000   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 5000   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
```

Comment: You can do it the same way as your single variable. Please edit your question to focus on one specific problem and show us some of your code. Are you struggling to create a button/event? Or are you struggling to work with the choropleth map and updating/changing it on the fly?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated my question with some code. To answer your question its the button that's got me stuck. I'm not sure how or where to add the button event so the code reads a new variable for styling.